# My app doesn't upload data to firestore, keeps in a loading loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a setup system to send name, email, profile pic, biography and **username**.
Then I did check if the username is taken into Firebase Firestore by QuerySnapshot (working) my problem is that when I change to an available username, the app enters into a loading loop and do nothing more. **It doesn't send to the database or anything else.**

I tried many times to solve this problem, but didn't find any solution yet. I moved the code, reorganized and nothing seens to solve.

The method is inside the **onClick** from a button.

Here's the code:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String name = setup_name.getText().toString();
                String username = setup_username.getText().toString();
                String userbio = setup_bio.getText().toString();
                String email = setup_email.getText().toString();
 
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && mainImageURI != null) {
                    Query mQuery = db.collection("Users")
                            .whereEqualTo("username", username);
 
                    mQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
 
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document: documentSnapshots){
                                if (document!=null){
                                    duplicate = document.getString("username");
                                    setup_username.setError("Ouch! This username is already taken. Please, try another.");
                                    setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                } else {
                                    if (isChanged) {
                                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        userid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                        StorageReference imagePath = storageReference.child("profile_images").child(userid + ".jpg");
                                        //StorageReference coverPath = storageReference.child("cover_images").child(userid + ".jpg");
                                        imagePath.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                                imagePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                        storeFireStore(uri, name, username, userbio, email);
 
                                                        FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.enviando_foto), FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.CONFUSING, R.drawable.ic_upload, false).show();
 
                                                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 
                                                    }
                                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                        String error = e.getMessage().toString();
                                                        FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.fail_to_update_profile_pic) + error, FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                                                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
 
                                    } else {
 
                                        storeFireStore(null, name, username, userbio, email);
 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
 
                } else {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(frameLayout, getString(R.string.empty_name), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(frameLayout, getString(R.string.empty_username), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else if (TextUtils.equals(username, duplicate)){
                        setup_username.setError("Ouch! This username is already taken. Please, try another.");
                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(frameLayout, getString(R.string.email_confirm), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(frameLayout, getString(R.string.pick_a_profile_pic), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
 
                }
            }
 
            private void storeFireStore(Uri uri, String name, String username, String userbio, String email) {
 
                if (uri != null) {
                    downloadUrl = uri;
                } else {
                    downloadUrl = mainImageURI;
                    //downloadUrl = mainCoverURI;
                }
 
 
                Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                userMap.put("name", name);
                userMap.put("username", username);
                userMap.put("userbio", userbio);
                userMap.put("email", email);
                userMap.put("image", downloadUrl.toString());
                //userMap.put("cover",downloadUrl.toString());
                firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userid).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.profileUpdated), FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.SUCCESS, false).show();
 
                            setup_progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                            FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.fail_to_update_profile) + error, FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
 
 
            }
        });
```

Here's a screenshot of the screen loop.

[image: Here's a screenshot of the screen loop]

Comment: Your snapshot listener might casing loop when you update user document. FIrst understand what snapshot listener actually does.

Comment: @PVartak I checked the Cloud Firestore Documentation, but without any success :/
Tried to remove the pic upload to the Storage and refactor the entire code, but it still the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. You likely don't need (or want) a "snapshot listener" for this use case.  You likely just want to do a one-time fetch to see if the given user name exists.
2. You likely want to use a TRANSACTION in Firestore to first read if a matching document exists and if not to `transaction.set()` a new document.  That way if others come in at the same time trying to create a doc with the same username, only one of the competing concurrent transactions will succeed.
3. Consider inserting the document to Firestore before you upload the item to Storage.  It is the document is Firestore that is the potential "race-condition".  Once you "own" the FS document, you can take your time to upload/update other data.

Comment: I tried to remove the pic Storage function, and let just the other ones but it still not working. It looks fine but doesn't upload the correct way, keeps in a loop. After the Query retrieves that the username isn't taken, the "else" function doesn't go. It only works when I set to the onClick, but then it will send all fields empty to the Firestore.